# Rails, From Controller to Model or Helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a structure where posts can be used as part of a forum, or they can be used as part of a group. The groups are a new addition, and originally, the forum controller handled listing the forums, but the post controller handled listing the posts within a forum.

Now that we are adding groups which have posts just like forums. I want use the same post list logic for both, but the group and the forum have different layouts, and slightly different access controls. I am thinking the post_controller probably needs to stop handling the listing of the posts.

This would be handled via partials in the group and forum views. But the code which handled the parameter processing and finally calling the model that used to be part of the post controller, where do i put this, from a structural standpoint? Seams to specific for a model. In a helper maybe?

Comment: How is a group any different from a named forum with a selective list of users?  Also, it's a bit difficult to discuss your situation without more specific structure and code.  It's doable, but less definitive to discuss the abstract and concept.

Comment: `code which handled the parameter processing and finally calling the model` what's that code? do you think it can be shared by both forums and goups? I'm not sure if this question fits stackoverflow guidelines since it may be really opinion based.

Comment: Groups have more stuff, files ect. You are correct they are very similar,we did discuss making them one, but took this separate path.  

And yes, I can see how it gets into opinions, if that is not allowed, i apologize. I guess i am looking for what would be best practice.